# Does Super Street Fighter IV AE 2012 & Ultra Street Fighter IV have Japanese voice lines?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv, ultra-street-fighter-iv

I'd love to purchase SSFIV & the upcoming USFIV, but I want some clarification.

If I purchase the game here (in the US), will it come with Japanese voice lines?

I find that listening to the Japanese voice lines a reprieve from the far inferior American voice lines.

Comment: You should get the Ultra Street Fighter IV box, then you will get all costumes up until now. If you preorder you get even some additional costumes for the new characters. The DLC does not include the costumes. You do not need any previous SF titles if you get the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All Street Fighter IV titles have Japanese and English voices and subtitles. You can even decide per character which voice they should have.

In older titles (read Street Fighter IV Vanilla and Super Street Fighter IV) you had to play the game through at least once (any difficulty) to be able to switch from English to Japanese.

Comment: So if I purchase it through Steam, there should be no problems, correct @ayckoster?

Comment: Yes I have the Steam version myself. You can access the menu like this: Options -> Sound Settings -> Voice Language.